# How to fix collapsing navbar that doesn't collapse in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My collapsible navbar is not working on this basic site, and I am not sure why. I have tried to reorder the CDN scripts, copied and pasted directly from Boostrap's docs, and have double checked the code a few times. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but can anyone help me and point out what is happening here? The toggle button appears, but doesn't do anything when clicked. This is being used with a Django project.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}The title I'm using{% endblock title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Log out</a>
            <a href="{% url 'password_change' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
            Change password</a>
              <a href = "{% url 'update' user.pk %}" class = "btn btn-primary ml-2">Update user profile</a>
              <a href = "{% url 'home' %}" class = "btn btn-primary ml-2">{{ user.username }}</a>
          </form>
        {% else %}
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Log In</a>
            <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
            Sign up</a>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content %}

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect attribute value in the toggle button:

```
data-target="navbarCollapse"
```

It should look like this (include the pound symbol):

```
data-target="#navbarCollapse"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried that, and it's still not working when I click the button.

Comment: @Atrum I just tested the code with the fix and it's working fine. Test it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVBVLY (resize your browser to test).

Comment: Weird, it still isn't working for me even on codepen. Maybe it has something to do with my browser/network? I'll try it on a different system. Thank you for your help!